# Aggregating object values into new object using _.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Suppose I have an array

```
var i = [{event: 'create', date: '03/11'}, {event: 'delete', date: '03/11'}, {event: 'put', date: '05/11'}, {event: 'delete', date: '06/11'}]
```

And then reduce them into an object as such:

```
var reduced = {03/11: 2, 05/11: 1, 06/11: 1}
```

What would be the best way of aggregating these results using _.js that would produce an object:

```
result = {03/11: [{event: 'create', date: '03/11'}, {event: 'delete', date: '03/11'}],
05/11: [{event: 'put', date: '05/11'}], 06/11: [{event: 'delete', date: '06/11'}]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic use case for `_.groupBy`.

```
var i = [{event: 'create', date: '03/11'}, {event: 'delete', date: '03/11'}, {event: 'put', date: '05/11'}, {event: 'delete', date: '06/11'}];

var result = _.groupBy(i, function(item) {
    return item.date;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n459T/)